# How can i get the size of all directories on windows using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get size of all folders in windows using Powershell.

the following:

```
  Get-ChildItem "D:\testdirectory" | Measure-Object -Property Length -sum
```

only gets for a particular directory , but i want it to scan all directories on the d:\ drive and give back the size of all folders including subdirectories .

How can i do this with Powershell ?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`PSTree` Module](https://github.com/santisq/PSTree) you can get the total size of all directories under `D:\` drive with:

```bash
Get-PSTree D:\ -Directory -Recurse -RecursiveSize
```

The module can be installed from the Gallery using:

```bash
Install-Module PSTree -Scope CurrentUser
```